# Can Git and .NET be friends?

Tags: asp.net, git, workflow

I'm a web developer thinking of moving work on our largest client's site to a Git workflow, but I am new to Git and am not sure how to integrate it with our client's .NET servers and IT folks.

The current workflow is: a co-worker and I work cooperatively on local versions of the site files, which we then push via FTP to the client's development server (accessible via VPN). Once the changes on their dev are approved, we have to catalog every changed file and email that list to our client's IT team. One of their team then manually pushes the changed files from dev to their production server. We are not allowed any access to the production server, as there are enterprise apps on it as well as the public-facing web directory.

A bit more awkwardness comes from the fact that the client's IT guys are all .NET developers and we are a Mac shop. Fortunately, the site files are 99%  HTML/CSS .aspx files, so they are easy for us to work with. Occasionally, the IT guys post an .ascx form control we have to incorporate, but for the most part changes travel from us to them.

As the site has grown, the labor of cataloging changed files has become a bottleneck and a point of potential failure. I want to automate deployment and provide revision tracking and rollbacks. From our side of the router Git looks like the way to go.

But what do I propose for the client side of the workflow? My understanding is Git is not native to .NET or IIS. I doubt I will be able to persuade our client's IT guys to install and use a new toolset. Their main job is enterprise app development, and I get the feeling they don't exactly live for the thrill of pushing our web updates live.

Comment: Team Foundation Server supports git.  Might be the way for you to push things (no pun intended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand you right. But git with .NET is pretty much the same as in other technologies.

Here is a git extension to use with Visual Studio:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c

Github is full of .NET projects.

I can't give you a advice to how to propose it. But git is definitly not a problem to use in VS or generally in .NET. They just have to switch.

You can also integrate git in your Team Foundation Server.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30474

> Git-TF is a set of cross-platform, command line tools that facilitate sharing of changes between TFS and Git. These tools allow a developer to use a local Git repository, and configure it to share changes with a TFS server. Using the tools, changes made in TFS can be pulled into a local Git repository, and changes made in the Git repository can be checked in to TFS. These tools can be used by individuals or teams collaborating using Git.

This way you could use both. TFS and Git for the same project. I think this could be a solution.

Comment: Sounds like there are solutions; just wanted to make sure there was some common ground between the technologies. Thanks!